# AutoNumber Column insertion in MS Access Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

here is my Database Structure

My table name is employee

```
First Column is "f_name" datatype "Short Text"
Second       is "l_name" datatype "Short Text"
Third        is "id"     datatype "AutoNumber" Primary Key
```

C# Code :

```
OleDbCommand com1 = new OleDbCommand("insert into employee values(@f_name,@l_name)", con);

com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_name", TextBox1.Text);
com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@l_name", TextBox2.Text);

com1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

this code gives an Error "Number of query values and destination fields are not the same"

I am using MS Access 2013 Database and ASP.Net C#.

Comment: you need to specify the column names of the values that will be inserted I would suggest reading up on how to format an INSERT query statement as well this is not that difficult to figure out..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to explicitly specify the columns in `INSERT` statement, otherwise it will treat all columns in `INSERT` statement and hence the error.

```
OleDbCommand com1 = new OleDbCommand("insert into employee (f_name, l_name) values(@f_name,@l_name)", con);
```

Your table has a column `id` which is `AutoNumber`, but since you didn't specify any columns explicitly in your query it would be like:

```
insert into(f_name,l_name,id) employee values(@f_name,@l_name)
```

Therefore you are getting the error.